# How to use Ubuntu and YouTube on a handheld device to protect from death threats?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, backup, youtube, remote, streaming

Suppose you fear you could meet someone who will threaten you with death.

Assuming the bad guy won't destroy your handheld (for example an Ubuntu Touch device) on sight, a barely decent form of protection would be to have your phone continuously stream its microphone to a remote server you do not have access to, programmed to publicly upload the recorded audio content on a popular YouTube channel on a regular basis, unless a circle of physically unavailable, neutral, trusted people for the threatener do not cancel it if nothing happened.

I want to know how to do that.

Question moved on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558256/how-to-use-an-handheld-device-with-gnu-linux-and-youtube-to-protect-from-death-t/558257#558257).

Comment: Another application would be to monitor what strangers are saying around your children.

Comment: Unfortunately, ubuntu-touch is EOF and therefore off-topic on this site. ubports is the new home of the project (a fork), but this is not on topic here.

Comment: Then please suggest what to do to best adhere to the rules; if you could fix the problem it yourself without just deleting the content it would be really appreciated. I'll be sure to see what you did and mimic it next time.

Comment: @Bruni it is not EOF (whatever that means). And it's allowed official use of the Ubuntu trademark (hence _Ubuntu_ Touch), so questions about it are still reasonable here, however few there may be. There are other reasons for this question to be closed, but "off topic" isn't really one of them I think.

Comment: @dobey Eof should read eol (end of life) and was a typo. If they are on topic that is great news, though I am  quite sure i have seen a lot of Ubports related questions being closed as off-topic since Canonical dropped Ubuntu touch. Regarding other reasons....if one ignores the somewhat strange introductory story, it is a perfectly valid technical question.

Comment: Well, I will refer you to a meta question, which I've just answered with how I think it is on topic: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18931/50737 Ubuntu 16.04 is still supported (not End of Life), and that's what Ubuntu Touch is currently based on, and questions about Ubuntu 16.04 are on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is  simplest procedure I came up with. It will work on any Ubuntu version, but in particular it will work on an Ubuntu touch device.

### On the handheld device

- **Ubuntu Touch specific:** Increase the size of the `system.img` of your Ubports phone with some extra gigs.
- **Ubuntu Touch specific:** Make your rootfs writable

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

- Proceed to install tor and rsync with

```
sudo apt install tor rsync
```

- Have this uncommented in your torrc

```
/etc/tor/torrc
----------------
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

- Start tor

```
service tor start     # Ubuntu touch
systemctl enable tor  # Any other Ubuntu version
systemctl start tor   # Any other Ubuntu version
```

- Get the onion address of your handheld

```
/var/lib/tor/ssh/hostname
--------------------------
your_onion_address.onion
```

- Record from microphone with

```
arecord ~/Music/recording.wav
```

### On the remote computer

- Install rsync and [`youtube-video-upload`](https://github.com/remorses/youtube-video-upload) (follow the instructions on the website to configure it for your account).
- Write the `recording.yaml` corresponding to your recording.wav.
- Run the sync_and_upload.sh script

```
sync_and_upload.sh
-------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env bash
watch -n <seconds_between_consecutive_syncs> rsync phablet@your_onion_address.onion /path/to/recording.wav &
watch -n <seconds_between_consecutive_uploads> python3 -m youtube_video_upload /path/to/recording.yaml
```

#### Known issues

- It is not adviced by Ubuntu Touch manual to write on the rootfs, so you will have to repeat the procedure every time you upgrade your phone;
- After receiving a call, microphone mutes in the recording;
- Tor should start at boot;
- everything should run in a container.